# Как работать с offline картой OpenStreetMaps на C#?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

Пишет cz десктопное ПО на С#, в котором должна отображаться карта.  ПО должно работать offline. Было выбрана карта от OSM и скачена из geofabrik.Вопрос есть ли возможность считать данные из файла и отобразить карту?
P.S. Интересует именно этот данный способ без загрузки данных в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Внутренняя начинка файлов `OSM`, это `xml`. Т.е. можно или напрямую работать с `xml`, или использовать что-то типа библиотеки `OsmSharp`. Но учтите, из-за особенностей структуры хранения, работать всё это будет очень долго. Так как у каждого объекта известны только `id` узлов. Т.е. что бы нарисовать объект, необходимо снова пройтись по всему файлу, найти узлы по `id`, и только тогда уже получить координаты.

Для реальной работы, Вам всё равно необходимо будет преобразовать сырые данные `OSM`, в какой-то оффлайновый формат, например в `shape`. Лучше всего загрузить данные в `PostgreSQL` утилитой `osm2postgis`, и уже результат экспортировать в любой оффлайн-формат. Или же по этим результатам, приложением `mapnik`, сгенерить растровые тайлы, которые можно использовать и оффлайн.

Comment: А есть ли способ из OSM или PostgreSQL, данные перевести в формат gmdb, для того чтобы пользоваться библиотекой Gmap.NET?